# SNMP not using community string in snmpd.conf

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, snmp

I'm trying to simply set up SNMP on a Red Hat system. I can walk the MIB tree just fine using the following command (from a different server): snmpwalk -v2c -c public HOST IP

However, when I try to set the community string in /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf, it doesn't walk the MIB tree. I have a feeling it's something simple, but for the life of me, I can't figure out why it's not working with the unique string I'm putting in. I do restart snmpd after editing the snmpd.conf file as well, so I'm not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong here.

The original config file is still there, all I added were the following lines (iglass is the string I want to use):

```
# First, map the community name "public" into a "security name"

#       sec.name  source          community
com2sec notConfigUser  default       iglass
rocommunity iglass
```

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen the `rocommunity` option.

By the looks of the config you pasted, you have edited the default snmpd.conf, so, changing `public` to `iglass` should suffice.

On the other hand I'd advise to use v3 instead of v2c, that's full of vulnerabilities.

Also, with v3 the config files get edited automatically. Example:

```
net-snmp-config --create-snmpv3-user -ro -a SHA -A (key-here) -x AES -X (2nd key here) (user here)
```

Then, after restarting snmpd, you walk the tree like this:

```
snmpwalk localhost -v3 -a SHA -A (key-here) -x AES -X (2nd key here) -l authPriv -u (user here)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a very similar issue, but I'm using a sub-agent. I found your question trying to answer my problem but I believe my answer is the same for your answer.

I was having an issue where I was trying to configure a sub-agent and it was not returning the oid from an snmpwalk. If I changed rocommunity to, in your example, iglass2 then it would work but only the sub-agent would return data.

I found that com2sec and rocommunity cannot overlap. If you simply comment out com2sec and use rocommunity, and optionally rwcommunity, set to what you need your configuration may work properly.

I hope this answers your question.